# I cannot set exception try except for OSError error: timed out in Exscript with python3

Tags: python-3.x

- The following code is not properly catching the `OSError` exception:

```
import socket
import os
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import Telnet
from Exscript.protocols.exception import TimeoutException
from Exscript.protocols.exception import LoginFailure


account = read_login()
conn = Telnet()
conn.connect('192.168.50.2')
conn.login(account)
try:
    conn.execute('sh clock')
except OSError:
        print('error')
        pass        
else:
    conn.execute('sh clock')
    print(conn.response)
    conn.send('exit')
```

#### Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "errortelnet.py", line 19, in <module>
    conn.connect('192.168.50.2')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Exscript/protocols/protocol.py", line 631, in connect
    conn = self._connect_hook(self.host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Exscript/protocols/telnet.py", line 60, in _connect_hook
    receive_callback=self._telnetlib_received)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Exscript/protocols/telnetlib.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Exscript/protocols/telnetlib.py", line 257, in open
    raise socket.error(msg)
OSError: timed out => telnet://192.168.50.2:23
```

Comment: The trace shows that the line `conn.connect('192.168.50.2')` raises an error, not `conn.execute('sh clock')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment:

#### From the `Traceback`:

```
File "errortelnet.py", line 19, in <module>
conn.connect('192.168.50.2')
```

- This is where the `Traceback` shows the error occuring

  - `conn.connect('192.168.50.2')` is not inside the `try/except` block

#### Alter your code to the following:

- `conn.connect('192.168.50.2')` is now in the `try` block

```
account = read_login()
conn = Telnet()

try:
    conn.connect('192.168.50.2')
    conn.login(account)
    conn.execute('sh clock')
except OSError:
    print('error')
    pass        
else:
    conn.execute('sh clock')
    print(conn.response)
    conn.send('exit')
```

#### Expected output of the exception:

> error